# Command line option to print from Internet Explorer or Mozilla firefox

Tags: command-line, firefox, internet-explorer

Is there a Command line option to print from Internet Explorer or Mozilla firefox?

for Ex. `C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -print -url www.google.com`

Comment: Did you make any research effort yourself? Did you try any of the suggestions from the amazingly clear and easy to obtain documents? Did they not work?

Answer (score 2):

According to the first Google [hit](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=2729795), this can be done:

**Tests:**

```
firefox.exe -print http://www.wtfpl.net/txt/copying/
firefox.exe -print http://www.wtfpl.net/txt/copying/ -printmode pdf
```